# Don't See Pull Requests on Heroku Pipelines Page

Tags: heroku, github

I'm an admin for our Heroku account and can see Review Apps on the Heroku pipelines page however I don't see open pull requests with the Create Review App option. I'm an  admin of the account so I'm not sure what it is. Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. I had to give Heroku access to my github account, even though it already had access to the corporate account I was a part of.

Comment: Good find. This is an annoying problem and not particularly evident to the user. Thanks.